SFMC Mobile Push - some Android devices are getting registered as Not opted in with Missing or Invalid Device Token error
We are experiencing an intermittent issue where some of our Android users are getting registered as Not Opted in with Missing or Invalid Device token error. Just to give a reference around 758 records in the last week have this missing token issue and in the same period 3916 contacts were correctly registered.
Push Attribute shows the "System Token" is indeed blank. Has anyone faced a similar issue, What could be the possible issue here? i have already checked the Server key is correct and re-updated on SFMC just to be sure, Majority of customers are registering correctly and we have tested with few contacts as well. This is a live app on Play Store. We are using SDK 7 if that makes a difference, planning to move to SDK 8 soon.

Open a support case.
